# Можно ли в данном случае обособить "всё же"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, риторика

Является ли в данном предложении правильным обособление единицы "всё же"?

**Вот смотрю на тебя, не понимая того, почему некоторыми, всё же, отвергается возможность использования предоставленного природой интеллекта.**

Человек это оправдывает риторикой и вводной конструкцией.

Answer (score 1):

1. У частицы ВСЁ ЖЕ **нет никаких оснований для обособления** (семантических, грамматических или структурных). Она не относится к тематике вводных слов, ее небольшой объем и ее позиция внутри предложения неудобны для обособления.

**Современный толковый словарь русского языка Ефремовой**

**ВСЁ ЖЕ**  1. Употребляется для усиления противопоставления чему-либо, ранее высказанному, соответствуя по значению сл.: всё-таки, всё равно. 2.Употребляется при подчеркивании содержания какого-либо слова или высказывания, соответствуя по значению сл.: всё-таки, ведь.
[https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/273790/всё](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/273790/%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91)

**Справочник по пунктуации** http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_115

ВСЁ Ж(Е) / ВСЁ Ж ТАКИ / ВСЁ-ТАКИ, частица; **не требует постановки знаков препинания.**   Слова «а всё ж(е)», «а всё ж таки», «а всё-таки», стоящие **в начале предложения**, могут отделяться запятой при интонационно-логическом подчеркивании: *А всё же, в чём дело?*

2. **Вывод.**

(1) Мы не можем обособить частицу  ВСЁ ЖЕ как вводное слово.

(2) Для интонационного подчеркивания требуется дополнительный союз и позиция в начале предложения, а здесь этого нет.

(3) Практические примеры подобного обособления (без дополнительных союзов и в середине распространенного предложения) отсутствуют.

Таким образом, обособление ВСЁ ЖЕ в данном случае **АБСОЛЮТНО НЕНОРМАТИВНО.**

Ну а что считать авторской риторикой — этот вопрос уже вне темы правописания.

Comment: *Употребляется для усиления противопоставления чему-либо, ранее высказанному, соответствуя по значению сл.: всё-таки, **всё равно*** — вы допускали обособление: *и всё равно, ведь где-то в вышине...*

Comment: Обратите ВНИМАНИЕ: а) на позицию в начале фразы (она всегда удобна для обособления); б) на дополнительный союз  И, НО, увеличивающий общий объем  выражения.  Малораспространенные сочетания могут иметь  хотя и близкое значение,  но  другие структурные возможности по сравнению с распространенными. Нам же надо построить  такую конструкцию, которая делится на интонационные фрагменты и читается естественно, а не абы как. Там каждое слово, каждый слог на счету, если уж говорить  о риторике, ага?   А не могли бы вы привести свой вариант правки, или вам все кажется идеальным?

Comment: У Розенталя: Примечание. Не являются вводными и не выделяются запятыми слова и словосочетания: авось, бишь, буквально, будто, вдобавок, в довершение, вдруг, ведь, в конечном счёте, вот, вряд ли, ВСЁ-ТАКИ, даже, едва ли, исключительно, именно, как будто, как бы, как раз, между тем, небось, никак, почти, поэтому, приблизительно, примерно, притом, причём, просто, решительно, словно, якобы и др. (частицы, наречия). Можете добавить туда и ВСЁ ЖЕ.  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122

Comment: Идеальным не кажется, но нормальным — да. "Предоставленный природой" звучит так, что природа реально взяла и предоставила, а оно образно, может, лучше чем-то заменить. "Всё же" вклинивается в структуру, и у меня обособление звучит.

Comment: Вариант разбивки на смысловые отрезки при чтении: ... почему некоторыми, всё же, отвергается //возможность использования //предоставленного природой интеллекта.  И как там себя чувствует ваше "всё же"? Вклинивается, да?  Действительно, вклинивается, причем так, что нельзя ни оставить на месте, ни обособить. Это и называется некорректное построение структуры предложения : ни общего смысла понять, ни прочитать. А уж о семантических оттенках высказанной мысли и говорить нечего. До этого просто дело не дойдет.

Answer (score 1):

"Всё же" может быть вводным, но это не рекомендуется.

Здесь оно чуть-чуть вклинивается в структуру (прерывая "*некоторыми отвергается возможность*"), поэтому хочется обособить. Думаю, что можно обособить в качестве исключения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]